# Laptop boots after trying multiple times

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, motherboard, power-supply

I have a Dell Latitude E5420. When I try to boot, I get the bios splash screen after which I only get a black screen and the drive activity light is also off. After trying to boot for a couple times the activity light starts to blink and windows boots successfully. Also if I am lucky windows boots on the first try.

When I tried to boot today I got a warning saying `battery is low press f1 to continue` I pressed F1 and windows successfully booted and when I checked the battery percentage it was at 73%.

These are the following things I have tried:

1. Trying automatic windows repair
2. Freshly installed windows
3. ATX reset - by removing the baterry and charging cable and holding the power button for 30 seconds
4. Running on mains power - Got stuck on black screen after bios splash screen

Also I tried booting with the charger plugged in and without the charger being plugged in I get the same problem
every time.

Is it a hard drive issue or power supply issue or maybe motherboard issue? I'm totally confused.

Thanks for your time

Comment: The likeliest (and cheapest) first try will be to get a new battery.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense that the battery is damaged and is self-discharging  causing your issues - along with misleading readings.

Answer (score 0):

All my previous laptops were able to run on mains only - without a battery.
Please try using your laptop to run without the battery to rule out the battery as a possible cause.

When running your laptop with a battery disconnect the mains power supply.
How much does the battery percentage gauge drop?

Increased internal resistance of your battery can produce misleading results about remaining battery capacity.

Comment: I tried running it on mains only but it got stuck at the black screen after bios splash screen... And about the battery I have used my laptop for 2 3 hours disconnected from mains power i.e. on battery backup